# Set libstdc++.so.6 location for compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

While build c++ package with GCC4.9 I am getting below error message.

```
'/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /local/p4clients/pkgbuild-S1NVe/workspace/build
```

I have overridden the CC and CXX with different Gcc compiler location in makefile, which also has the same so file under different folder.
I have added that folder location also in LD_LIBRARY_PATH still compiler is using **/usr/lib64/** instead of **/mypath/lib64**.
**/usr/lib64/** is GCC4.5.
How can i tell compiler to use so file from differenet location.

Comment: after adding LDFLAGS += -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc in makefile getting new error fx_zlib_crc32.c:(.text+0x6d6): first defined here

Answer (score 0):

You need a version of the shared object built for your operating system.  The DSO you are trying to use is not compatible with GCC 4.5.  It was compiled against GCC 4.9 or later.  Replacing the system `libstdc++.so.6` library will make the entire system unsupported.

Comment: I am already having build shared objects, only problem is compiler is using older once only (I have two versions of gcc compiler on build machines)